# Использование конструкции "быть пристрастным в отношении к кому-либо/чему-либо"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Для текста песни в плане ритмики подходит такая конструкция. Грамотно ли ее использование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Пристрастен в отношении к" звучит непривычно, но это не означает, что неграмотно. Если издание "Филологические записки" допускает подобное в научном стиле:

> ...Лесков пристрастен в отношении к «малому народу»... ,

то вряд ли кто станет придираться к такому употреблению в песенном жанре. Это всё, что я могу сказать в общих чертах.